# react-pose flip animation e.g thumbnail goes full screen

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-animations, pose

want to create a portfolio/projects page where user click on thumbnail it goes full screen and other page comes in

i guess i can achieve this using [pose-flip](https://popmotion.io/pose/)

https://codesandbox.io/s/fourth-react-pose-example-qj92p problem is how i can do it with multiple elements on page

this is the [sample site](http://clapat.ro/themes/satelite-wordpress/classic-portfolio/)

i'm new to react, when i click the thumbnail how to remove all others ( fade ), we can do it simply in jquery not selector